# Is there any way to control DirectShow VSFilter programmatically?

Tags: video, directshow, directshow.net, subtitle

I'm trying to set up a subtitles file to DirectShow VSFilter programmatically.
There is a way to do so through its property pages but I can't find any documentation regarding its API or even if it has one.

Is there any sort of API, Interop, anything which would allow to set up a subtitle file for VSFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific documentation on VSFilter, however it's open source software. So you can download source code, reference its interface definition e.g. in MPC-HC source `\Mpc-hc\src\filters\transform\vsfilter\IDirectVobSub.h` and use the interface to control the filter programmatically.

```cpp
    interface __declspec(uuid("EBE1FB08-3957-47ca-AF13-5827E5442E56"))
IDirectVobSub : public IUnknown 
    {
        STDMETHOD(get_FileName) (THIS_
                    WCHAR* fn   // fn should point to a buffer allocated to at
                                // least the length of MAX_PATH (=260)
                 ) PURE;

        STDMETHOD(put_FileName) (THIS_
                    WCHAR* fn
                 ) PURE;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize this filter is a part of MPC-HC project.