# Setting DirectShow VSFilter file name through code

Tags: vb.net, directshow.net

I've been searching for a way to do this using VB.NET and DirectShowNET for many months. Thanks to the question  [Is there any way to control DirectShow VSFilter programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179308/is-there-any-way-to-control-directshow-vsfilter-programmatically/25328054#25328054) asked last week, I'm on the right track but need help getting over the final hurdle.

As per the answer to the above question, I can get hold of the filter's interface and call put_FileName(). However, when I check the filter in the running graph, the file name is either junk or blank. Here's how I load the filter:

```
 Dim clsidVobsub As New Guid("{93A22E7A-5091-45EF-BA61-6DA26156A5D0}")
 Dim filterVobsub As IBaseFilter
 Dim type__2 As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsidVobsub)
 filterVobsub = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type__2), IBaseFilter)
 Graph.AddFilter(filterVobsub, "My VobSub")
 Dim vobSettings As ISettingsInterface = DirectCast(filterVobsub, ISettingsInterface)
 Dim fn As String = "C:\Leta\testing.srt"
 Dim hr as Integer = vobSettings.put_FileName(fn)
```

That seems to work as it should, so I think the problem lies with the way I'm trying to marshall the function call in the interface definition.

```
 <PreserveSig()> _
  Function put_FileName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> fn As String) As Integer
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: The ISettingsInterface is my own. It's declared like this:

```
    <ComImport(), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity(), Guid("EBE1FB08-3957-47ca-AF13-5827E5442E56"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
    Public Interface ISettingsInterface

        <PreserveSig()> _
        Function get_FileName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> fn As String) As Integer

        <PreserveSig()> _
        Function put_FileName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> fn As String) As Integer

    End Interface
```

SOLUTION: It was actually already working! I was running a test project and hadn't bothered rendering the video branch. I mistakenly thought VSFilter would display the file name as it does when it picks up an SRT with the same name as the video. Apparently it doesn't when you set the file name through the interface. So instead of checking the filter's property page in my graph in GraphEdit, I should simply have rendered the video and I'd have seen the subtitles in the video window.

Comment: `ISettingsInterface` and `put_FileName` declarations don't look well.

Comment: @Roman R. I've edited my question to show the interface declaration. Could you clarify what doesn't look right?

Comment: Works for me. Check `hr` value, maybe the filter rejected the file (missing or broken).

Comment: hr returns 0. I'm using version 1.0.1.5 of the filter (August 2008) in case that helps.

Comment: FYI I stepped from the C++ side, inside VSFilter and I saw the calls gets there correctly. Old version of VSFilter might explain the problem, you might want to try a [newer thing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpc-hc/files/Standalone%20Filters%20-%20Win32/Filters_v1.7.6_x86/MPC-HC_standalone_filters.1.7.6.x86.7z) or [from here](http://nightly.mpc-hc.org/mpc-hc_apps/vsfilter/old/).

Comment: I found the solution, Roman. Explanation above. Many thanks for your help!